# Debugging issue when trying to load the code to my ios device

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, xcode4.2

When I run my app using my ios device. the compiler immediatly goes to the following code:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

and I get the following message from "All Output":

warning: No copy of SubstrateLoader.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
Couldn't register XXXXX with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.(gdb)

Any Idea why this is happening??

Comment: The complier has no problem when running ios 5.0 simulator it only happens for the ios device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll mumble the canonical IT-Support mantra:

> Did you try turning it off and on again?

From time to time, the debugging session on the device disconnects without the device actually noticing it, thus blocking any further attempts to open a new debugging session.

If that happens, your best option is to reboot the device…